# Best practice to access static object, 'public static' or 'private static' with getter

Tags: java, oop, dictionary, static

I have a class `Foo` which contain a `static Map<String, String> myMap` and some `public static` methods which manipulate `myMap`.

`myMap` is common Map("common content") for some classes in my project.

Those classes, which need `myMap`, only read data from it and always change data from `myMap` using methods from `Foo`.

My question is: How is the best practice to declare and access `myMap`, in my case? As `public static` and access like `Foo.myMap` or as `private static` and acces like `Foo.getMyMap()` which will return a copy of `myMap`( `new HashMap<String, String>(myMap)` ). Or this depends only by my preferences?

Comment: Check this blog: https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Comment: In the static context, yes - use a getter. However see the other answer, try to avoid static data if possible. Maybe dependency injection frameworks can insert the same instance of the class containing a (non-static) Map wherever you need it?

Comment: This one is more relevant: http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/27

Comment: @rechandler: I like this article and the blog itself. However, Yegor doesn't provide an answer to replace `public static final` fields since Java doesn't support "global" variables.

Comment: Is your `Foo` class only managing the common map? If so, try to refactor Foo into a singleton/enum and allow access to the map through getters and setters. If Foo does more, then think about refactoring the common map to its own singleton/enum class. As multiple classes might interact with the data simultaneously, you also need to consider concurrent access and thread-saftiness in your design.

Comment: @it `Foo` manage only `myMap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps in the following order:

1. Try to avoid `static` in general, because it is not in regards to OOP principles.
2. If you insist to use `static`, the field must be `final` regardless of the access way usage.
3. Prefer `getters` over `public` visibility modifier.

But yes, it depends *always* to your preferences.

Comment: 1. How am I supposed to access the same object in more classes without `static`? 2. How can I change data from object if it is `final`?

Comment: 1. Use singleton, however, I try to avoid it as well. Unfortunately, I have no answer for "global" variables in Java - so better stick with the 2nd suggested way: `static final`. 2. A class that is `final` cannot be changed itself, however can call the methods. A `final Map` still can put/remove the items. `final` is meant to disallow a `Map` be replaced itself or set to `null`.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood keyword `final` meaning. Thanks.

Comment: @raul1ro: Welcome, hope I helped to make things a bit clearer for you :)

Comment: @Nikolas actually there are two concepts: Objects and Data-Classes. While OOP is often seens as Objects only, Data-Classes have their use as well. OOP is not about providing accessor methods to internal state but drive the objects state through method invocation. Data-Classes on the contrary are loosly speaking only a container for data and therefore providing getters and setters or transformation methods is a natural thing. Robert "Uncle Bob" Martin explained it clearly in his book `Clean Code` if you want to read up on it.

Comment: @RomanVottner: I am generally against treating objects ad dumb data containers.  I have no alternative answer for this problem described at the OP's question in regard to pure OOP. Thank you for the book suggestion :)